# Spring Security Filter is not being triggered by configuration

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am configuring the security of my REST and I don't know how I can secure my methods, however allowing a filter to trigger to set my Authority

```
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(PERSISTENCE_SERVICE_URL)
    .hasAuthority(AUTHORITY_PERSISTENCE_SERVICE)
    .and()
    .csrf()
    .disable();
```

And in my Filter which extends `OncePerRequestFilter` does something like this

```
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
this.authenticationImpl.init();
  String jwt = request.getHeader("jwt");
  String refresh = request.getHeader("refresh");
  if(jwt != null) {
   this.jwtPropertyExtractor.commitJwt(jwt, refresh);
   String jwtId = this.jwtPropertyExtractor.getIdentityId();
   String securityRole = this.jwtPropertyExtractor.getSecurityRole();
   this.authenticationImpl.setIdentityId(jwtId);
   this.authenticationImpl.updateSecurityRole(securityRole);
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(this.authenticationImpl);
}

filterChain.doFilter(request, response);  }
```

So when I place `.hasAuthority(AUTHORITY_PERSISTENCE_SERVICE)` in my configuration, my filter is not even being triggered but i need him to set my authentication.

Comment: Your configuration show you haven't registered your custom filter

Answer (score 0):

Ok i added

```
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorisationFilter(),
            BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }

  @Bean
  public JwtAuthorisationFilter jwtAuthorisationFilter() {
    return new JwtAuthorisationFilter(jwtExtractor(),
        authenticationImpl());
  }
```

Now its working fine thx for that hint :>